# What version of the .NET Framework is included in Windows 7(build 7600)?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, version

What's the default version of the .NET Framework that is included in Windows 7 (build 7600)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that is .NET 3.5, with SP1.

Comment: Would you please post the references ?

Comment: @Mohammad - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework has a Versions table about half way down the page

Comment: Further reference: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Top10TipsWorkingDevelopersShouldKnowAboutWindows7.aspx

Answer (score 5):

**.Net 2.0 SP2** and optionally **.Net 3.0 SP2** and **.Net 3.5 SP1**

[image: Which Version of .NET is Built into Windows]